# highcharts round decimals for gauge labels

Tags: highcharts, formatter, gauge

I have this gauge here and can't figure out how to round the decimals on the round label to one. [image]

tried this:

```
    title: {
        text: when,
        style: {
            fontSize: fontSizeMin + 4 + 'px'
        },
        formatter: function () {
            Math.round(this.y * Math.pow(10, 1)) / Math.pow(10, 1); 
        }
    },
```

but didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
 Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0)
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/24227/